# Can a Perl program sniff packets from multiple NICs simultaneously?

Tags: perl, network-programming, packet-capture

so I am planning to make a network analyzer using Perl. But before I start I have to answer this question, can a Perl program actually sniff packets in multiple NICs simultaneously? a feature of the program im going to make is that it needs to sniff the packets in the whole LAN within a switch. Is this possible in Perl?

Comment: `multiple NICs != whole LAN within switch`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sniffing packets in the whole lan is not possible. It is only possible if your switch supports it. Many swith has an option to copy all traffic to one of its port for monitoring/sniffing.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_mirroring

http://www.miarec.com/knowledge/switches-port-mirroring